# Navigating through

Tags: android

I am new to android and, of course, I have some problems.  Your help will be appreciated.

I am trying to create two activity classes: one of them is ListActivity class.

Normal activity class pass a data(string) to ListActivity class(using bundle) to display in the list.

Once we click on the particular item in the list, I again want to go back to the normal activity class to do some further operation. I don't know if it is possible or not.

Waiting for your reply, Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are working with a List in your ListActivity , you need to have a Listener:

The method [getOnItemSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getOnItemSelectedListener%28%29) will help you fetch the item you click.

After you get the item, you can use [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) to go back to the Normal Activity

**EDIT 1**:

Example:

```
    s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,int pos, long id) 
        {

        if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Your Particular Item name"))
        {


          Intent intent = new Intent (ListActivity.this, NormalActivity.class);
              startActivity(intent);


        }
         else
          {
           ...//do something else
          }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the listener of list item click, just call Activity.finish() and normal activity will back, If you want pass data to normal activity, call startActivityForResult instead startActivity  When you launch list activity, and call setResult before finish ListActivity.
You can get data by override the normal activity's onActivityResult.

Get data
startActivityForResult -> setResult -> finish -> get data form onActivityResult.